How can I calculate the shape of a convolution layer automatically in Pytorch?
I want to calculate the output dimension of any Pytorch convolution layer automatically.
When creating bigger CNN's, the calculation of the output of the last conv. layer gets pretty tedious.
Is there a way to do that automatically on the fly without using nn.LazyLinear()?
Code example:
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=2)

self.feature_dim = [ADD CODE HERE]

self. fc1 = nn.Linear(self.feature_dim, 256)

Thanks, the help is highly appreciated!
I have tried using the formula [(W−K+2P)/S]+1 and implement it in the code but doing that for every layer is almost more work to implement than to calculate it simply by hand.
Is there a uniform way to read the output shape from Pytorch directly?
EDIT:
Using this 2 functions one can extract the shape of the output at any point during the forward path. torch.numel() gives the total number of elements of the given tensor.
self.flat_features = self._get_conv_output((1, 84, 84))

def _get_conv_output(self, shape):
    with torch.no_grad():
        input = torch.rand(1, *shape)
        output = self._forward_features(input)
        return output.numel()

def _forward_features(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
    return x


You can use the "meta" device to create a "fake tensor" without allocating any memory and using flops for computation.
See the following minimal example:
import torch
from torch import nn

conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=2)

x = torch.zeros([1, 1, 8192, 8192], device="meta")

y = conv1(x)
y = conv2(y)
y = conv3(y)

print(y.shape)

Here are some more notes on the "fake tensors": https://pytorch.org/torchdistx/latest/fake_tensor_and_deferred_init.html
I hope this helps!
